# jquery post success function not returning html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript/jquery function in a perl program that returns a complete HTML page and I'd like to use jquery's .post to submit CGI values to the program and re-load the page for further processing based on the data submitted.

Consider the following mcve:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
my $cgivars = CGI->new;
my $data = $cgivars->param('DATA');

my $something = "This is some data.";

my $display = qq|Content-type: text/html\n\n<http><head></head><body>The data submitted was $data</body></http>|;
my $postdata = qq|Content-type: text/html\n\n
        <http><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function postData() {
        \$.post("jqpost.cgi",{DATA:"$something"});
        }
        </script>
        Click the button to submit some data<br>
        <button value="submit" onclick="postData()">Submit</button>
        </body></html>|;

if ($data) {
    print $display;
} else {
    print $postdata;
}
end;
```

When I use

```
$.post("jqpost.cgi",{DATA:"$something"});
```

firebug's console shows a 200 (OK) and the All/HTML tab shows the page as I'd like to see it returned, with the data passed being used as expected. I get that the above code doesn't include a function to manage the result returned.
So I'm trying to use a function that will load the page that I know is being returned, using

```
$.post("jqpost.cgi",{DATA:"$something"},function(data) { document.write(data);});
```

The page starts to load in the browser, but the page never completes loading. Apache's logs doesn't show any additional data.

What can I use for a success function to properly/completely display the whole page returned from the server?

Comment: What are you receiving from your program, a string of HTML, JSON, something else? Is it really the "*whole page*" or just the `<body>`, or some other, element to append/insert to a specific place? What's your "*[MCVE]*" HTML before you fire your Ajax request? What response do you get? What precise result/output do you expect or require?

Comment: I've restructured the post to use an MCVE that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the `document.open`. `document.write` is open the document.

```
document.write("Hello there!!!");
document.close();
```

no more spinning.